# Using python on a Google Cloud Windows Server

Tags: python

I've just installed Windows Server 2019 on Google Cloud Compute Engine, so I can host my python apps 24/7 but I can't install python because of this error:
`0x80070659 - This installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator.`
I was wondering if there's anything I can do to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:
I just needed to run the setup file as administrator.